# Calculated measure MDX through Pivot Table Excel

Tags: excel, mdx, pivot-table, olap

I am connected to OLAP cube, I created a pivottable.

I would like to know if with the OLAP tool of excel is possible to calculate the number of distinct invoice number taking acount the current filters like year, country and region of the pivot table ?

I tried with Countdistinct it gives me the same result for each country.
DistinctCount([PO TYPE].[PO NUMBER].[PO NUMBER])

Answer (score 0):

Try using `COUNT` instead:

```
Count(
   Exists(
     [PO TYPE].[PO NUMBER].[PO NUMBER].MEMBERS,
     [Geography].[Country].CURRENTMEMBER,
     "MeasureGroupName"
   )
 )
```

You need to replace "MeasureGroupName" with a measure group name in your cube